# JS curry recursion handling empty parameters

Tags: javascript, recursion, currying

Below I have a basic recursion to return values that are passed, I'm wondering how to handle if a function is without any parameters - curry()(), but still allow the value to be returned if the same function is called with a parameter - curry()()("b")

```js
function curry(x) {

    if (x === "b") {
        return "Banana";
    }

    const t = (...y) => {
        if (y[0] === "a") {
            return "Apple"
        }
        if (y[0] === "S") {
            return "Strawberry"
        }
        
        //if() {
          //return "Hello World"
        //}

        return t;

    }
    return t;
}

curry("b") //? Banana
curry()("a") // ? Apple
curry()()()()()("S"); //? Strawberry

curry()(); //? Hello world
```

Comment: You can test whether `arguments.length` is zero.

Comment: FWIW, `y` is an array. `y == "a"` does implicit type conversion. Better: `y[0] === "a"`.

Comment: @felix-kling your right, have updated post

Answer (score 1):

You really can't get the behavior you're proposing.

Think about these two lines:

```js
curry()()()()()("S"); //=> Strawberry  // (1)
curry()(); //=> Hello world            // (2)
```

The first one (1) could be rewritten as

```js
let foo = curry()();                   // (1a)
foo()()()("S");                        // (1b)
```

But we already know from the second line (2) that

```js
curry()() //=> "Hello world"
```

which is not a function, so `foo()` is an attempt to call `"Hello world"` as though it were a function.

I don't think there is any way around this.

You could write a function that you could call over and over, always returning another function, one with a property you could test, so that, say

```js
curry()().value //=> "Hello world"
// and
curry()()()()()("S").value //=> "Strawberry"
```

But that's a different question.